# How to create a service in Azure to monitor a database if certain conditions on the records are met?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I need to create a webpage table reservation system for a restaurant. One of the requested features, is to send the customer a reminder via text message or email if the table reserved time is within 5 mins and the customer has not checked in yet.

For example, it's 6:55 PM, reservation time is at 7:00 PM, and guest has not checked in yet catch that event.
How can I set a service in Azure to monitor records on the Azure SQL database to check whether time record is within a given time? I am sorry if my question is too general, but i can't find anywhere to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hangfire and schedule to send the notification at the specific datetime:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Console.Write("test"), new DateTime(2016, 6, 4, 16, 22, 0));
```

ps: in order to proper execute this your app must be running with always on mode